# Add my own shipping methods in oscommerece

Tags: php, customization, oscommerce

I want to add an own shipping method during `checkout_shipping.php`. Something like a dropdown list, from that the customer will select his shipping method and enter his own account no in a textbox. How should I implement this?

Comment: Oscommerce is a turd and you should replace it with something better.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I'm currently working on a project that involves OScommerce. I agree with Keyo, but I know that sometimes is not that it easy to migrate ;)

The payment methods are contribution, if you would like to build your own you have to build two files (at least, because there is one of the files that is the language)

Here you have direct access to a payment module made for mercadopago Argentina (like PayPal)

http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/6504

If you check the zip file you are going to see that the files have to be added in the catalog - include
then you have the one I already told (language)
and modules - payment.

I made a few payment methods my self, it's not hard, but you have to remember that OScommerce is like 6 years old, so the code is not the best ;)

I hope this helps.

P.S. If you want more payment methods you can look here: 
addons.oscommerce.com/category/Payment_Modules